# Tikzpicture caption spacing

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions

I am trying to add a caption to the following tikzpicture but its creating a huge space underneath. I'm not sure how to fix this. [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{angles, calc, intersections, positioning, quotes, backgrounds}
        \usepackage{pgfplots,caption}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
        \begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
             \clip (-2,-3.5) rectangle (0,3.5);
             \draw (0,2) circle(1);
        \end{scope}
                \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4);
            \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0);`

            \node at (0,3)[right] (1){\footnotesize $a_{2}$}; 
            \node at (0,1)[right] (2){\footnotesize $a_{1}$}; 

            \node at (-1,3)[right] (3){\footnotesize $\gamma$}; 

            \filldraw[black] (0,1) circle (1pt);
            \filldraw[black] (0,3) circle (1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{figure}{Example}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
\clip (-2,-3.5) rectangle (0,3.5);
```

in your document, which, apart from clipping, adds a rectangle path that is taken into account in the bounding box computation. You can either make the rectangle smaller, e.g.

```
\clip (-2,-0) rectangle (0,3.1);
```

or just exclude the rectangle from the bounding box computation via `overlay`,

```
 \clip[overlay] (-2,-3.5) rectangle (0,3.5);
```

MWE (with unnecessary packages and libraries removed):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node font=\footnotesize]
 \begin{scope}
 \clip[overlay] (-2,-3.5) rectangle (0,3.5);
 \draw (0,2) circle[radius=1];
 \end{scope}
 \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4);
 \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0);`

 \node at (0,3)[right] (1){$a_{2}$}; 
 \node at (0,1)[right] (2){$a_{1}$}; 

 \node at (-1,3)[right] (3){$\gamma$}; 

 \filldraw[black] (0,1) circle[radius=1pt];
 \filldraw[black] (0,3) circle[radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Example}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Needless to say that you could just draw an arc and abandon `\clip` to get the same result.